# Theme/style Angular 2 reusable component libraries

Tags: angular, themes, shared-libraries, styling, reusability

**General problem**

I want to style reusable Angular components to match the style of the specific client project.

I maintain the reusable components in a separate project and generate an npm package out of it. That package is published to a private NPM repository (Sinopia) and then installed into multiple client projects.

The general styling is - of course - specific to the component, but color and font - for example - should match the client project.

How can I best apply styles such as color and font, defined in the client project, to the reusable components?

**Current implementation**

At the moment I am using https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library to scaffold the reusable component library.
It generates some Gulp tasks which let me build a dist version.
Publishing that dist and using the published package works just fine but the built code makes it hard for me to figure out a working theming strategy.

The Gulp build task will inline both the HTML and CSS resources in the final code.

A sample Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-messages',
    templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./messages.component.scss'],
})
export class MessagesComponent {

    constructor(private messagesService: MessagesService) {

    }

}
```

Gets 'flattened' during build to

```
var MessagesComponent = (function () {
    /**
     * @param {?} messagesService
     */
    function MessagesComponent(messagesService) {
        this.messagesService = messagesService;
    }
    ...
    return MessagesComponent;
}());

MessagesComponent.decorators = [
    { type: Component, args: [{
                selector: 'app-messages',
                template: "<div *ngFor=\"let message of messages\"> <div class=\"message {{message.type}}-message\"> {{message.message}} <i class=\"fa fa-remove\" (click)=\"removeMessage(message)\">x</i> </div> </div>",
                styles: [".message { line-height: 36px; padding: 4px 20px; margin: 2px; position: relative; } .message .fa-remove { position: absolute; right: 20px; cursor: pointer; } .info-message { background-color: #005CAB; color: white; } .error-message { background-color: red; color: white; } "],
            },] },
];
```

The `MessagesComponent.decorators` now contains the styling in-line.

**Concrete questions**

1. Is using the https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library generator a good choice for creating component libraries? Or are there better ways?
2. How do I have to 'override' the color and font styling of my
   reusable components?

I had hoped to be able to use scss variables in the component library which could be (re-)defined in the client project. Something like

Reusable component `messages.component.scss`:

```
.info-message {
   background-color: $primary-color;
   color: white;
 }
```

Client project `/style/_style-vars.scss`:

```
$primary-color: #005CAB;
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

**FOLLOW UP**

I got one step further:

I now use CSS3 variables and that gets me almost there:

In the reusable component, I define my SCSS variables as follows:

```
$primary-color: var(--ang-ux-primary-color, #5FB0FD);

.ang-ux-primary {
  background-color: $primary-color;
}
```

and in my client project I define the styles like this (style.scss):

```
// styling reusable components
:root {
  --ang-ux-primary-color: #666666;
}
```

This works, but it seems I cannot use SCSS variables in the definition of my CSS variable:

```
$primary-color: #666666;

// styling reusable components
:root {
  --ang-ux-primary-color: $primary-color;
}
```

results in an empty $primary-color in the reusable component.
I opened a separate thread for this issue: [Using SCSS variable inside CSS3 variable definition not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534058/using-scss-variable-inside-css3-variable-definition-not-working)

Comment: [This walkthrough](https://www.usefuldev.com/post/Angular:%20create%20a%20library%20that%20supports%20Angular%20Material%20theming) shows how to create component libraries which support Angular Material themes. It is Angular-cli based though but may still be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

1. Add scss styles folder to project
2. Add to build task - copy styles folder to 'dist' folder
3. install your npm package  to client project (npm i )
4. Import styles from node_modules, SASS/SCSS says it should start with ~; you should @import '~/dist/scss/somefile to project scss file.

Answer (score 1):

What I've tried in this context (note that I'm using Angular v6):

For example you are calling  in app.component.html

If your app.component.css or app.component.scss contains the styling that should be applied in ,

Set the viewEncapsulation for the component to none in your app.component.ts:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Which will allow all your styling that you have in your app.component.(s)css to flow beyond to reach the library you are using.

This quick fix is what made component styling go beyond the current component and be applied to the libraries used.

Comment: I think there should be an other way than disabling the ViewEncapsulation.

Comment: Yes, if there is, I'm all ears