# Using SCSS variable inside CSS3 variable definition not working?

Tags: css, variables, sass

I am figuring out how to apply styling to a reusable Angular component from within a client project. See [Theme/style Angular 2 reusable component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571437/theme-style-angular-2-reusable-component-libraries) => look for "follow up".

I now have one issue remaining:

I try to use a SCSS variable inside a CSS variable, but that CSS variable does not seem to be defined:

```
$primary-color: #666666;

// styling reusable components
:root {
  --ang-ux-primary-color: $primary-color;
}
```

In other component (in other component library, built separately):

```
$primary-color: var(--ang-ux-primary-color, #5FB0FD);
```

$primary-color seems to be empty... not #666666, neither #5FB0FD.

Comment: Changed, thanks :-)

Comment: There is no such `var` function in sass. In your case the value of $primary will be just that: `var(--ang-ux-primary-color, #5FB0FD)`. Does the assigned styles fail to render the `$primary-color`? What is the css output?

Answer (score 4):

To convert a Sass variable to a CSS variable, you need to [interpolate it](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
--ang-ux-primary-color: #{$primary-color};
```

Once you've converted your Sass variable into CSS, there's no getting it back. Therefore, in your other component you should maybe stick with pure CSS. The following will use `#5FBOFD` if `--ang-ux-primary-color` is undefined.

```
--ang-ux-primary-color: var(--ang-ux-primary-color, #5FB0FD);
```

Comment: No, thats not a good answer. The output with or without interpolation is the same. And this does not answer the question.

Comment: I fleshed out my answer to address the second part of the poster's question. As to the interpolation, I tried it out on CodePen and it is required.

Comment: good but the first part is still wrong. You don’t need to interpolate variables if you use the variables as properties values. Just use the variable name: `$primary`.

Comment: @muecas, so you say my solution (`--ang-ux-primary-color: $primary-color;`) should have to work?

Comment: Hi, I guess I need to review my project as it all seems to work (in a very limited setup): https://plnkr.co/edit/13J7cMe5SatN76ySTtOQ

Comment: Yes it should. I created and compiled an example with your code and all worked fine. That’s why i asked about the compiled code you were getting. Why do you think the resulting variable is empty?

Comment: You absolutely have to [interpolate scss variable to apply the value to a css variable](https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/dyYxPXO).